# Determining if a subgroup is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I need some clarification on this problem. These are my answers and I was wondering if they are correct or not. Any help is appreciated.

Determine whether the indicated set A is an ideal in the indicated ring R.

a). $A = \Bbb Q$ in $R = \Bbb R$

$\sqrt3 \in \Bbb R, r \in \Bbb Q, r \sqrt 3 \notin \Bbb Q$ This is not an ideal.

b). $A = 2 \Bbb Z$ in $R = \Bbb Q$

$r = 2 \in 2 \Bbb Z, s = \frac {3}{2}, rs = 3 \notin 2 \Bbb Z $ Not an ideal.

c). $A = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}$ in $R = \Bbb Z_{10}$

$r=8 \in A, s = 9 \in R, rs = 72 \notin A$. Not an ideal.

Comment: 72 mod 10 = 2$\in A$

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that we have to take the modulus for $rs$.

Comment: don't you like my ultrashort answer? : )

Comment: @janmarqz lol I did. I just fell asleep. Usually everyone is pretty serious on here.

Comment: hehehee, i was crying a river XD

Answer (score 1):

a) and b) are correct, except that you have to exclude $r = 0$ in a). c) is wrong, as $72 = 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. The given set is an ideal for the same reason $2\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$: multiplication of a number by an even number always yields an even number.

Answer (score 0):

(a) and (b) are correct but (c) is wrong. In $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, the element $72$ is equal to the element $2$ because we are working modulo $10$. This means $rs=72=2\in A$, so your example doesn't work. It actually turns out that $A$ is an ideal in this case.